# How to call a python function which contains input function to a HTML

Tags: python, html, sql, flask, chatbot

I have built a function in python that takes user input using input() and stores that into SQL.

I want to build a front end with flask and when I'm trying to call this python function in Html it displays none.

I tried a similar solution provided over StackOverflow, but as my function contains input(), it is not working.

```
def my_link():
    x=input('your name: ')
    return (x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/my-link/">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want my Html page to initiate the flask function i.e ask for user input and further my function also stores that user input to SQL server.

But when I'm trying to call this function(which has user input) over HTML, it displays none.

Comment: I don't think flask works like this. Go through flask docs.

Comment: Get input from user using an HTML form in a Flask template. Then handle the values in Flask application. Example of handling form: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/examples/tutorial/flaskr/templates/blog/create.html

Comment: Is there any other way, my problem doesn't want Html to be taking input?